# Converting を from Hiragana to Romaji

Tags: translation, word-choice, rōmaji

I realize that it's usually better to just learn / use hiragana but I have been asked to look into coding up a solution to convert from Hiragana/Katakana to the modified Hepburn Romaji.

One point I would like some advice on is the conversion of:

```
かいものをします
```

I see some converters changing this to:

```
kaimonooshimasu
```

and others to:

```
kaimonowoshimasu
```

Is there one or the other that I should aim for with the Modified Hepburn?

Comment: What is the purpose of this romanized text?  Will this romanized text be used later to reproduce the kana rendering?  Is this intended for humans to read?  Running everything together produces a largely unreadable result.  If you're interested in a human-readable output, have a look at Wiktionary's coding module: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:ja

Comment: My opinion is that wo is better, just for the sake of unambiguity/specificity.

Answer (score 4):

As [Eiríkr Útlendi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5229/eir%c3%adkr-%c3%9atlendi) mentioned in a comment, the correct romanization for を in modified Hepburn is `o`.

For traditional Hepburn, the correct romanization is `wo`.

To blatantly steal his wikipedia link as well, [here's the reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Particles). For a programming project, you should be able to use the table at the end of that page for a dict/hash translation. (with some special handling for ん)

> kaimonooshimasu

is correct for modified hepburn, but since you lack the word seperation functions of kanji/kana alternation with romaji, people usually seperate words with spaces when using romaji.

Comment: Just thought I'd provide a link to a simple Javascript implementation of the translation table referenced in that Wikipedia article: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/ecbea1a0c7a8a6cb21d80886488045f1

It's not perfect -- there are still some edge-cases it doesn't handle -- but it works for 95+% of words, which is good enough for my personal use case.

If someone knows a light-weight existing library that accomplishes this conversion function (but with all edge-cases correctly handled), please let me/us know.

Answer (score -1):

The correct romaji way is wo.

"O" is how you pronounce it and it's unnecessary since the first thing we learn in Japanese is that を has one use and it's  pronounced "o" but written  "wo".

We can also distinguish better what each word is in "kaimonowoshimasu".

Comment: Citation for "correct way"? There are multiple ways to transliterate Japanese into English. They are "correct" for different purposes

Comment: The asker also specifically mentioned Modified [Hepburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization), which renders the particle を as _"o"_.